# Do Red-Black tree and AVL tree have same balance condition?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

For example:

An unbalanced tree:

```
  4
/   \
1    11
    /
   7
 /  \
5    9
```

After balance, it will become AVL tree:

```
    11
   /   \
  4    7
 /    / \
1    5   9
```

However, if the unbalanced tree is R-B tree like this:

(\\ means read pointers. \ means black pointers.)

```
  4
/   \\
1    11
    /
   7
 //  \\
 5    9
```

Is this a legal R-B tree? Or I should make it balance just like what I did to the tree?

Comment: That is an RB tree, yes. And as you can see, the balancing condition for AVL trees is not identical.

Comment: `\\ means read`[sic] `pointers. \ means black pointers.` - red&black *pointers*? I seem to remember *node* colours - can you present a definition of *what* to colour *how* and the *balance condition*?

Answer (score 2):

The balance condition of AVL trees is different from the balance condition of Red-Black trees. An AVL tree is, in a sense, more balanced than a Red-Black tree.

In an AVL tree, for every node `v`, the difference between the height of `v`'s right sub-tree and the height of `v`'s left sub-tree must be at most 1. This is a very strict balance property compared to the one imposed by the Red-Black tree. In a Red-Black tree, no simple path from the root to a leaf is allowed to be more than twice as long as any other. This property results from the [five color conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties) a binary search tree must satisfy in order to be considered a valid Red-Black tree.

Your example Red-Black tree is indeed not balanced in the AVL sense because the difference between the height of the root's left sub-tree and the height of its right sub-tree is 2. Nevertheless, the tree is balanced in the Red-Black sense as it satisfies the five Red-Black color conditions.

The AVL balance condition implies that [the height of an AVL tree is bounded by roughly 1.44log(n)](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node112.html) while there's nothing preventing the height of a Red-Black tree from being greater: the Red-Black tree balance condition only implies [a bound of 2log(n)](http://doctrina.org/maximum-height-of-red-black-tree.html) on the height.

The fact that AVL trees tend to be shorter than Red-Black trees seems to suggest they must perform better. This is not necessarily the case: an AVL tree is indeed generally faster to search because it's more balanced than a Red-Black tree. But the reason an AVL tree is so well balanced is that keeping it balanced is computationally harder than keeping a Red-Black tree balanced. In particular, the [AVL rotations](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~paton/readings/liblitVersion/AVL-Tree-Rotations.pdf) make insertions and deletions in an AVL tree slower in comparison to these operations in the corresponding Red-Black tree.